# REST cURL request for Docusign Recipient on all Envelopes

Tags: php, rest, curl, docusignapi

So I'm hoping my title isn't too vague, but I'm trying to use the REST request for recipient status on all envelopes. Where I'm having trouble is how to create a variable for the Envelope IDs since I want to get a response for all the recipients on all envelopes. Does this make sense?

The example from Docusign's REST API is: `https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`. The part I'm having trouble with is {envelopeId}. I've tried `$envelopeId = $_GET["envelopeId"]` which throws up the Undefined Index error. I know this is very basic programming, but I'm not too embarrassed to ask for help. Feel free to request more information.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're asking here, can you please elaborate some more?  Are you just saying you're having trouble parsing the envelopeId that is returned in the response from previous api calls?

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with the listener. It's making a request for the recipient status. We're building a page to display the recipient name, status of envelope and date signed. I can make a request for the envelopes themselves, but I need to get the recipient names. The REST code examples (http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeRecipientStatus) use one hardcoded envelope id, but I need to get all envelopes with recipient names. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through the DocuSign Console but I'm not sure if this exact request is possible through the API, at least not currently.  There are several ways to get envelope information on multiple envelopes through the api, but I don't believe you can filter by recipients right now.  Instead you can filter by things like status (or even status changes), created_date, sent_date, folders, etc.  This can be done through calls such as **Get Folder Envelope List** or **Get Envelope Status Changes**.

To accomplish through the Console you can use the new **Reporting** tab, follow these steps:

```
1.  Login to Console.
2.  Select Reports tab at top of screen.
3.  On the following screen select "Envelope Recipients Report"
```

[image]

If you select `Customize` then you can filter by dates and or recipient names.

The other alternative you have is to retrieve a list of envelope ids, then make the `GetEnvelopeRecipientStatus` api call on each one to retrieve the information on a one envelope per api call rate.

Comment: Reports doesn't seem to be available in our demo account console. Since we want to have this display in our custom interface, we'd rather have it displayed there. Also, since there is the potential for there being a thousand envelopes and around twenty users, wouldn't we quickly hit that 1000 call limit? I was wondering if it would be possible to build a key => value array and then do a foreach loop to place each value within the REST url request? What do you think?

Comment: So I was able to get all the envelope ids into a key => value array. Would this be a bad idea to do what I propose to do? Would this be equivalent to your second suggestion, running a REST cURL request for each one?

Comment: I ask because I know that in the GitHub eSignature SOAP version, with the Get Status page, I was able to show the info we needed. Was that making an API call for each envelope?

Comment: I got all the envelope IDs into an array, but when I make my REST call, I get a 500 error.

Comment: Yes I believe the GitHub SOAP sample makes an individual call for each one of the envelopes.  But the call I was talking about, which might only partially solve your issue, was the Get Envelope Status for more than one Envelope:     http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Get Envelope Status for more than one envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%20API%20References%7C_____69